# Qt mouse leave event while button is pressed

Tags: c++, qt, events, mouseevent

I need to detect if the mouse pointer leaves my custom widget even if a mouse button is pressed.

According to [this post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/10678-Qt-widget-enter-leave-event?p=56627#post56627), Qt does not cause a `leaveEvent` in case a button is pressed, at least not in version 4.4. I am working with 4.7.3, but still do not get a `leaveEvent` in the described case. I also tried with the various drag-related events, but no luck. Does anyone have an idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did something similar to @gregseth.

> Write your own MouseLeaveEvent that is invoked from MouseMoveEvent
>   when the mouse's position is outside of the widget's boundary.

As Qt's documentation says "Mouse move events will occur only when a mouse button is pressed down"

Comment: This is not really elegant in my opinion, but it seems that Qt does not provide us with anything else. I wonder wether this is not a more common problem and should be worth getting its own event.

Comment: You probably misunderstood, the alternative you posted is exactly what am talking about. When u click a widget, the mousePressedEvent for that widget is invoked and not the parent. In other terms what I meant was write a mouseLeaveEvent for your button.

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood the "something similar", because gregseth proposed changing the parent widget.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is an even better option than using the mouse events of the parent widget: You can implement the `mouseMoveEvent` function of the child widget and get the `QMouseEvent::pos()` position which is relative to the top left corner of the widget. That means, if you know the size of the widget (use for example `QWidget::rect()`), you can compute within the widget if the mouse pointer is still on the widget or not without having to change the parent widget.

Comment: I posted this answer due to a misunderstanding of blueskin's answer. Both answers propose the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. The only workaround I found is to manage the `mouseMove` event of the parent widget, and to check if the position of the cursor is inside or outside the boundaries of the widget you want the event on.

Comment: I got the same solution, but had a problem: press button at the parent's parent widget.